# Django schedule framework doesn't work like it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-scheduler

I'm trying to get to work the schedule framework for django but it doesn't look right and it's functually broken as well, although only in the front-end. My guess would be that Javascript (jquery?) doesn't work correctly.

[This is how it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaaTy.jpg)

vs

[this is how it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYXug.jpg)

Does anybody have an Idea what the Problem might be?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you comment on their issues page on github?

Comment: No, because this is probably user error and I thought the github issue page is for bug and not help. Hmm. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/issues/348
This might just be my Problem, thanks a lot daniel!

Comment: It's probably not user error. I used this plugin a while ago and had the same result. If you followed their documentation and failed you should post an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging in the framework's github issue page and apparently there are lots of people with the same issue. I have come to the conclusion that just looks like this out of the box and that I did nothing wrong (at least to cause this look). I will just try to make my own views and templates.